# Not able to set background color to a view in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color

Edit: everything is fine with the code, Android Studio is not deploying changes to app version 4.1.3

Im trying to change the background color of view(Relative layout and rootView) at runtime

but its not working at all here is the code

```
rootview = findViewById(R.id.rootView)
rootview.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2))
```

Layout code/file, I'm using relativeLayout as the main layout here which is overridden by another view completely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:cb_color="@color/mainButtonColor1"
        app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip" />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:cb_color="#B71C1C"
        app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

If I set the background in XML it works fine

Comment: Try `ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourColor)`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @TehleelMir - In which lifecycle method are you setting the background color?

Comment: I'm testing in onCreate method, but its not working at all, in java i used to do the same thing and it used to work fine, but in kotlin is weird

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are using a Relative layout. So maybe, your relative layout is overridden or covered by another View (like `view 2` is covered by view 1 and view 3 ). And when you change the background of `view 2`, this function worked but you don't see it because it is being `covered by view 1 and view 3`. You should try Liner Layout to replay.

[image]

Comment: i don't think thats the case, i have updated the answer with layout file code you can see it now

Comment: Maybe we have a problems in `resources.getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2)`. Because your XML work with me (I mean `rootview.setBackgroundColor()` worked)